# Is it possible to get the Email address of a user using the Chatbot in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-hangouts

For my Dialogflow chatbot I need to identify the users using the chatbot. So is it possible to fetch their Email addresses. I am using Hangout for integration.

Answer (score 0):

The bot can access some user data which includes the email address.

So the answer to your question is yes.

See https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/bots#bot_access_to_user_data

Answer (score 0):

**Entities** are pieces of information that Dialogflow captures from a user message. This is what I'd recommend using to get the email address from one of your users.

In your dialogflow console, you simply need to set up the appropriate user intent (maybe "provide email address"). Inside that intent you can create an **action** that captures an email address entity.

Dialogflow includes default settings to capture pieces of information like email addresses, doing much of the work for you.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-overview